# Illustrated equation (with TikZ) with evenly spaced lines (and some homogeneous highlight)

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations, highlighting, annotations

If possible, I would like to achieve this in a simpler and better way, namely:

1. using a single equation where lines are spaced in a regular way
2. the cup and bracket are big enough
3. each highlighting rectangle should have the same height
4. each line of the equation should be horizontally aligned with its corresponding explaining rectangle on the right part of the figure.

Before achieving this in a custom way, I was playing:

- with equations in an `array` environment (i.e. `$\bigcap\left(\begin{array}{c}...\end{array} \right)$`),
- with `\bigcap`,
- with `\phantom` to highlight subparts with rectangles of the same height, but the outcome wasn't fully satisfactory.

P.S.: find at the end of this post an attempt that uses the TikZ matrix library as suggested, but the alignment between each left line and its illustration is lost (note that using one single matrix did not solve the alignment issue)

[image: Equation example]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\La}[1]{\mathcal{L}_{#1}}
\newcommand{\pre}[1]{\overrightarrow{#1}}
\newcommand{\shuf}{\textnormal{shuf}}
\newcommand{\highlight}[2][black!5]{\mathchoice%
  {\colorbox{#1}{$\displaystyle#2$}}%
  {\colorbox{#1}{$\textstyle#2$}}%
  {\colorbox{#1}{$\scriptstyle#2$}}%
  {\colorbox{#1}{$\scriptscriptstyle#2$}}}%

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[xshift=0cm,yshift=0.2cm]
\node {$\highlight{\shuf(\shuf(\shuf(\shuf(\Sigma^*\setminus \pre{\La{\sigma}},s),s),s),s)}$};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=0cm,yshift=-0.4cm]
\node {$\highlight{\shuf(\shuf(\shuf(\pre{\La{\sigma}},s),s),s)}\highlight[cyan!10]{~s~\Sigma}$};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=0cm,yshift=-1cm]
\node {$\highlight{\shuf(\shuf(\shuf(\highlight{\Sigma^*\setminus\La{\sigma}},s),s),s)}\highlight[cyan!10]{~s~\Sigma}$};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=0cm,yshift=-1.6cm]
\node {$\highlight[pink!30]{\Sigma^+~s~}\highlight{\La{\sigma}}\highlight[cyan!10]{~s~\shuf(\shuf(\Sigma^*,s),s)}$};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=0cm,yshift=-2.2cm]
\node {$\highlight{\shuf(\Sigma^*\setminus\La{\sigma},s)}\highlight[cyan!10]{~s~\shuf(\shuf(\Sigma^*,s),s)}$};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=0cm,yshift=-2.8cm]
\node {$\highlight[pink!30]{\Sigma^+~s~}\highlight{\shuf(\Sigma^*\setminus\pre{\La{\sigma}},s)}\highlight[cyan!10]{~s~\shuf(\Sigma^*,s)}$};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=0cm,yshift=-3.4cm]
\node {$\highlight{\Sigma^+~s~\Sigma^+~s~\Sigma~s~\Sigma^+~s~\Sigma}$};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=4cm,yshift=0cm]
\filldraw[fill=black!5,draw=black,densely dotted] (0,0) rectangle (4,0.5);
\draw (0,0.1) -- (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,0.1);
\node at (1.9,0.23) {$w_{1,i}\notin\pre{\La{\sigma}}$};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=4cm,yshift=-0.6cm]
\filldraw[fill=cyan!10,draw=black,densely dotted] (3.6,0) rectangle (4,0.5);
\filldraw[fill=black!5,draw=black,densely dotted] (0,0) rectangle (3.6,0.5);
\draw (0,0.1) -- (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,0.1);
\node at (1.75,0.23) {$w_{1,i-1}\in\pre{\La{\sigma}}$};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=4cm,yshift=-1.2cm]
\filldraw[fill=cyan!10,draw=black,densely dotted] (3.6,0) rectangle (4,0.5);
\filldraw[fill=black!5,draw=black,densely dotted] (0,0) rectangle (3.6,0.5);
\draw (0,0.1) -- (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,0.1);
\node at (1.75,0.2) {$w_{1,i-1}\notin\La{\sigma}$};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=4cm,yshift=-1.8cm]
\filldraw[fill=pink!30,draw=black,densely dotted] (0,0) rectangle (0.5,0.5);
\filldraw[fill=cyan!10,draw=black,densely dotted] (2.6,0) rectangle (4,0.5);
\filldraw[fill=black!5,draw=black,densely dotted] (0.5,0) rectangle (2.6,0.5);
\draw (0,0.1) -- (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,0.1);
\node at (1.55,0.18) {$w_{j,k}\in\La{\sigma}$};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=4cm,yshift=-2.4cm]
\filldraw[fill=cyan!10,draw=black,densely dotted] (2.6,0) rectangle (4,0.5);
\filldraw[fill=black!5,draw=black,densely dotted] (0,0) rectangle (2.6,0.5);
\draw (0,0.1) -- (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,0.1);
\node at (1.55,0.18) {$w_{1,k}\notin\La{\sigma}$};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=4cm,yshift=-3cm]
\filldraw[fill=pink!30,draw=black,densely dotted] (0,0) rectangle (0.5,0.5);
\filldraw[fill=cyan!10,draw=black,densely dotted] (3,0) rectangle (4,0.5);
\filldraw[fill=black!5,draw=black,densely dotted] (0.5,0) rectangle (3,0.5);
\draw (0,0.1) -- (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,0.1);
\node at (1.7,0.23) {$w_{j,k+1}\notin\pre{\La{\sigma}}$};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=4cm,yshift=-3.6cm]
\draw (0,0.1) -- (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,0.1);
\filldraw[fill=black!5,draw=black,densely dotted] (0,0) rectangle (4,0.5);
\draw[gray] (0.5,0) -- (0.5,0.1);
\draw[densely dashed,gray] (0.5,4.1) -- (0.5,0.3);
\draw[gray] (2.6,0) -- (2.6,0.1);
\draw[densely dashed,gray] (2.6,4.1) -- (2.6,0.3);
\draw[gray] (3.0,0) -- (3.0,0.1);
\draw[densely dashed,gray] (3.0,4.1) -- (3.0,0.3);
\draw[gray] (3.6,0) -- (3.6,0.1);
\draw[densely dashed,gray] (3.6,4.1) -- (3.6,0.3);
\node at (0.25,0.25) {$\Sigma^+$};
\node at (0.5,0.2)   {$s$};
\node at (1.75,0.25) {$\Sigma^+$};
\node at (2.6,0.2)   {$s$};
\node at (2.8,0.24)  {$\Sigma$};
\node at (3.0,0.2)   {$s$};
\node at (3.35,0.25) {$\Sigma^+$};
\node at (3.6,0.2)   {$s$};
\node at (3.8,0.24)  {$\Sigma$};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=-4cm,yshift=-1.3cm]
\draw[thick,rounded corners=2pt] (1,-2.3) -- (0.85,-2.3) -- (0.85,1.8) -- (1,1.8);
\node at (0.4,-0.3) {\scalebox{3}{$\cap$}};
\draw[thick,rounded corners=2pt] (6.95,-2.3) -- (7.1,-2.3) -- (7.1,1.8) -- (6.95,1.8);
\node at (7.5,-0.3) {\scalebox{1}{$=\emptyset$}};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

A solution using the TikZ matrix library as suggested.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\newcommand{\La}[1]{\mathcal{L}_{#1}}
\newcommand{\pre}[1]{\overrightarrow{#1}}
\newcommand{\shuf}{\textnormal{shuf}}
\newcommand{\highlight}[2][black!5]{\mathchoice%
  {\colorbox{#1}{$\displaystyle#2$}}%
  {\colorbox{#1}{$\textstyle#2$}}%
  {\colorbox{#1}{$\scriptstyle#2$}}%
  {\colorbox{#1}{$\scriptscriptstyle#2$}}}%

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}
\matrix [row sep=-2.4mm,matrix of nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=)] {
$\highlight{\shuf(\shuf(\shuf(\shuf(\Sigma^*\setminus \pre{\La{\sigma}},s),s),s),s)}$
\\
$\highlight{\shuf(\shuf(\shuf(\pre{\La{\sigma}},s),s),s)}\highlight[cyan!10]{~s~\Sigma\hspace{-2em}\phantom{(\pre{\La{\sigma}})}}$
\\
$\highlight{\shuf(\shuf(\shuf(\highlight{\Sigma^*\setminus\La{\sigma}},s),s),s)}\highlight[cyan!10]{~s~\Sigma\hspace{-14.3em}\phantom{\shuf(\shuf(\shuf(\highlight{\Sigma^*\setminus\La{\sigma}},s),s),s)}}$
\\
$\highlight[pink!30]{\Sigma^+~s~\hspace{-6.3em}\phantom{\shuf(\shuf(\Sigma^*))}}\highlight{\La{\sigma}\hspace{-6.3em}\phantom{\shuf(\shuf(\Sigma^*))}}\highlight[cyan!10]{~s~\shuf(\shuf(\Sigma^*,s),s)}$
\\
$\highlight{\shuf(\Sigma^*\setminus\La{\sigma},s)}\highlight[cyan!10]{~s~\shuf(\shuf(\Sigma^*,s),s)}$
\\
$\highlight[pink!30]{\Sigma^+~s~\hspace{-6.5em}\phantom{\shuf(\Sigma^*\setminus\pre{\La{\sigma}},s)}}\highlight{\shuf(\Sigma^*\setminus\pre{\La{\sigma}},s)}\highlight[cyan!10]{~s~\shuf(\Sigma^*,s)\hspace{-6.5em}\phantom{\shuf(\Sigma^*\setminus\pre{\La{\sigma}},s)}}$
\\
$\highlight{\Sigma^+~s~\Sigma^+~s~\Sigma~s~\Sigma^+~s~\Sigma}$
\\
};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=0cm,yshift=0cm]
\node[anchor=west] at (-4.6,0) {\scalebox{3}{$\cap$}};
\node[anchor=east] at (4.4,0) {\scalebox{1}{$=\emptyset$}};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=6.5cm,yshift=0cm]
\matrix [row sep=0mm,matrix of nodes] {
\filldraw[fill=black!5,draw=black,densely dotted] (0,0) rectangle (4,0.5);
\draw (0,0.1) -- (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,0.1);
\node at (1.9,0.1) {$w_{1,i}\notin\pre{\La{\sigma}}$};
\\
\filldraw[fill=cyan!10,draw=black,densely dotted] (3.6,0) rectangle (4,0.5);
\filldraw[fill=black!5,draw=black,densely dotted] (0,0) rectangle (3.6,0.5);
\draw (0,0.1) -- (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,0.1);
\node at (1.75,0.1) {$w_{1,i-1}\in\pre{\La{\sigma}}$};
\\
\filldraw[fill=cyan!10,draw=black,densely dotted] (3.6,0) rectangle (4,0.5);
\filldraw[fill=black!5,draw=black,densely dotted] (0,0) rectangle (3.6,0.5);
\draw (0,0.1) -- (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,0.1);
\node at (1.75,0.1) {$w_{1,i-1}\notin\La{\sigma}$};
\\
\filldraw[fill=pink!30,draw=black,densely dotted] (0,0) rectangle (0.5,0.5);
\filldraw[fill=cyan!10,draw=black,densely dotted] (2.6,0) rectangle (4,0.5);
\filldraw[fill=black!5,draw=black,densely dotted] (0.5,0) rectangle (2.6,0.5);
\draw (0,0.1) -- (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,0.1);
\node at (1.55,0.1) {$w_{j,k}\in\La{\sigma}$};
\\
\filldraw[fill=cyan!10,draw=black,densely dotted] (2.6,0) rectangle (4,0.5);
\filldraw[fill=black!5,draw=black,densely dotted] (0,0) rectangle (2.6,0.5);
\draw (0,0.1) -- (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,0.1);
\node at (1.55,0.1) {$w_{1,k}\notin\La{\sigma}$};
\\
\filldraw[fill=pink!30,draw=black,densely dotted] (0,0) rectangle (0.5,0.5);
\filldraw[fill=cyan!10,draw=black,densely dotted] (3,0) rectangle (4,0.5);
\filldraw[fill=black!5,draw=black,densely dotted] (0.5,0) rectangle (3,0.5);
\draw (0,0.1) -- (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,0.1);
\node at (1.7,0.1) {$w_{j,k+1}\notin\pre{\La{\sigma}}$};
\\
\draw (0,0.1) -- (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,0.1);
\filldraw[fill=black!5,draw=black,densely dotted] (0,0) rectangle (4,0.5);
\draw[gray] (0.5,0) -- (0.5,0.1);
\draw[gray] (2.6,0) -- (2.6,0.1);
\draw[gray] (3.0,0) -- (3.0,0.1);
\draw[gray] (3.6,0) -- (3.6,0.1);
\node at (0.25,0.1) {$\Sigma^+$};
\node at (0.5,0.1)   {$s$};
\node at (1.75,0.1) {$\Sigma^+$};
\node at (2.6,0.1)   {$s$};
\node at (2.8,0.1)  {$\Sigma$};
\node at (3.0,0.1)   {$s$};
\node at (3.35,0.1) {$\Sigma^+$};
\node at (3.6,0.1)   {$s$};
\node at (3.8,0.1)  {$\Sigma$};
\\
};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=4.53cm,yshift=-2.1cm]
\draw[densely dashed,gray] (0.5,4.25) -- (0.5,0.3);
\draw[densely dashed,gray] (2.6,4.25) -- (2.6,0.3);
\draw[densely dashed,gray] (3.0,4.25) -- (3.0,0.3);
\draw[densely dashed,gray] (3.6,4.25) -- (3.6,0.3);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: using TikZ matrix library]

Comment: 1) Don't use minimal, it isn't intended for code examples. 2) Have a look at the TikZ matrix library.

Comment: This, or the `tikzmark` package.

Comment: I just use the TikZ matrix library (1 matrix for the formulae on the right, one matrix for the illustrations on the left): it avoids having a lot of begin{scope}...end{scope}, but I could not get the same height for each cell: consequently the bottom of each formula is not completely aligned with the bottom of its illustration on the left.

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution?  If the answer is "yes", in the second image, is the right part of the last line correct?  It is what you want, or are you looking for different horizontal spaces?  And, one more question: on the right side, the $\in$ and $\not\in$ are they to be vertically aligned?